# ESP-12F Schematic Diagram

Tags: esp8266

I have done a couple of prototyping using Wemos D1 Mini and would like to use the ESP-8266 12F Board directly without the devkit. Attached is the schematic for the same. Please let me know if i missed something in the design.

1. 10K resistor for pullup (GPIO-0, Reset, CHPD) & 10K for pull down (GPIO 15) (Is 10K good value)
2. 0.1uf Capacitor at Vcc(is this sufficient)
3. P2(programming header) connects to tx, rx, vcc & gnd. ( Some suggest to power externally MCU while flashing, which means to disconnect the Vcc from P2 Header Pin 3, not sure about this)
4. Any other improvements to the circuit.

Appreciate your valuable time & look forward to learn more. [image: 8266]

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple circuit for ESP8266 chip and can be modified more,
First of all let's answer your questions:
1- 10K is a normal pull resistor for designers, but if your system is very sensitive on current drawn, or your system is battery powered, it's better to increase pull-up resistor to reduce power consumption while key pressed or I2C transmission.
2- It's very necessary to add decoupling capacitor/s, it's reduce L (Inductance) of power line and also suspends noise that digital systems make and better stability. Remember to use ceramic capacitor, when electrolyth Caps are have inside L that's not good for decoupling.
3- In case of programming, there's much more current drawn by chip, so it's a clever idea to use external power for programming, but it can cause voltage problem if you connect two power source together, to prevent this, add a slider key or jumper to prevent this problem.
As another suggestions, I recommend to add a capacitor to boot and reset pin and to ground for more stability and reset debouncing and prevent noise on reset pin.